# Is the freebusy query from google calendar api falsy?

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have tried to figure this for a while now, but can't wrap my head around it. I make a freebusy request to a calendar that has a date from 8am to 10am. If put the following times into the request body I get the busy array back with the calendar being busy from 8am to 10am (which is correct): 1am to 8am, 6 am to 11am.
Now if I put the time from 8am to 10 am the busy array is empty. Same when I put in 9am to 11am or 9am to 10am.
Timezone is CET+2 as in the calendar setting.
Does anyone have an idea why the freebusy request would behave that way?

Here is how it looks: [image]

[image]
This is the first call. I deleted the ID for security reasons. it shows the calendar is busy from 8-10.

[image]

[image]
This is the other request. In the request Body it asks for the Time between 8 and 10. suddenly the room is not busy anymore.

Answer (score 0):

### You have to change the freebusy request timeMin and timeMax properties

Decrease the time by 2 hours, as you can see the time returns is +2 hours and the second query doesn't include that timelapse. For this specific case the query should look like:

```
{
  "timeMin": "2021-05-03T06:00:00.00Z",
  "timeMax": "2021-05-03T08:00:00.00Z",
  "timeZone": "CET",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```